# Repeating Sprite Cocos2d 3.0

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, scroll

Im trying to make a scrolling affect in the background of my app

The sprite moves from north to south

This is successful but how can I repeat the sprite sprite to continuously do this? The sprite moves south and the end of the png file is seen, how could it be made that it repeats at this point so the sprite never ends? Thank you!

```
- (void) Buildings
{

rightBuilding = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"rightBuilding.png"];
rightBuilding.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
rightBuilding.position = ccp(0.9f, 0.5f);
[self addChild:rightBuilding];

}

- (void) scrollBuildings:(CCTime)dt
{

rightBuilding.position = ccp(rightBuilding.position.x, rightBuilding.position.y - .5);

}
```

Comment: Did you try creating another CCSprite instance and attaching to first one.. ? This one actually depends on Screen size and your image size that how many CCSprite instances you have to create. When one image goes out of bounds again place it at the beginning and do move animation on that.

Comment: How could I accomplish that?

Comment: Break the problem down and solve it step by step. Instead of trying to all of it at once, try having one sprite moving down the screen and repositioning itself back on top when it's off screen. Then try to do it with two sprites in different sequence.